# Limit string and count items left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that is a list of items for example:

```
-------------------------------- <- Div limit
this is a test | test | another string | abc | string test
-------------------------------- <- Div limit
```

What i want to do is something like this:

```
-------------------------------- <- Div limit
this is a test | test | +3
-------------------------------- <- Div limit
```

How can i accomplished something like that? is possible?
The text is dynamic, it can be only (one text and +5) or all text if it fit in the div.

Comment: If you really want this, try it with arrays and check  the number of characters overlap the limit, if so, just count the rest and don't add them...always reserve the 3 or more character spaces for the " +2" and count the " | " as 3 characters also.

Comment: Are you okay to do this using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a fixed, maximum character count, it would be more friendly to use all the width that is available.  Here's a solution that not only uses all the space available, but works with any font size or style.  You can even put links and images in the list entries!

This technique renders the list, then removes the entries that go past the right end of the DIV.

Assume this HTML:

```
<div id="theList" class="List" style="width:40ex">
  <span class="Entry">this is a test</span>
  <span class="Divider">|</span>
  <span class="Entry">test</span>
  <span class="Divider">|</span>
  <span class="Entry">another string</span>
  <span class="Divider">|</span>
  <span class="Entry">abc</span>
  <span class="Divider">|</span>
  <span class="Entry">string test</span>
  <span class="Divider">|</span>  <!-- Extra divider, for the count. -->
  <span class="Count">0</span>    <!-- The count. -->
</div>
```

The above "width:40ex" is just to force this DIV to be short.  You should replace that with the width that you need.

Assume this CSS style:

```
.List {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px dashed gray;    /* Only for debugging. */
}

.Entry {
  padding-left: 0.5ex;
  padding-right: 0.5ex;
  background-color: LightGreen;    /* Only for debugging. */
}

.Count {
  padding-left: 0.5ex;
  padding-right: 0.5ex;
  background-color: Orange;    /* Only for debugging. */
}
```

Assume this JavaScript code:

```
// This uses jQuery.
var listDiv = $("#theList");
var listWidth = listDiv.innerWidth();
var entries = listDiv.children(".Entry");
var firstLeft = entries.eq(0).offset().left;
var countSpan = listDiv.children(".Count");
var nHidden = 0;
var i;
var entry;
var needWidth;
for (i = entries.length; 0 <= --i; /**/ ) {
  entry = entries.eq(i);
  if (nHidden != 0) {
    countSpan.text("+" + nHidden);
    needWidth = countSpan.offset().left + countSpan.outerWidth()
  } else {
    needWidth = entry.offset().left + entry.outerWidth();
  }
  if (listWidth < needWidth) {
    entry.css("display", "none");
    entry.next().css("display", "none");
    ++nHidden;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
if (nHidden == 0) {
  countSpan.css("display", "none");
  countSpan.prev().css("display", "none");
}
```

**Note**:  This code may not handle an empty list.  This code may not handle the situation wherein even the first entry is too long.  *I leave these issues as an exercise for the reader.*

[Go see it on my JSFiddle! >>](https://jsfiddle.net/David_Patow/mo00wcfm/3/)

Comment: Further ideas for extra credit: (1) Make each word a clickable link.  (2) When the user clicks on the "+3", show a dropdown list of the 3 hidden words, also as links.  (3) If the list represents folders within a path, hide the folders in the _middle_ of the path, rather than at the end.  For some systems, this is more useful.  (4) When the user hovers their mouse over the outer DIV, show a tooltip that displays the path part that corresponds to the horizontal position within the DIV.  This changes, as the user moves left & right, and makes it easy to inspect the path in limited space.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxlength=20;
var result=[];
var text="a | b | c dd d | ashBdhsjxbxjybxbxhxbxbxjbx";
//get the words
var words=text.split(" | ");
//loop trough
for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
 //if word fits into content
 if(words[i].length<maxlength){
    //set maxlength to left space
    maxlength -=words[i].length;
    //add word to result
    result.push(words[i]);
 }else{
    //add sth like " 3+"
    result.push((words.length-i-1)+"+");
    //stop fetching words
    break;
 }
 }
 //add the line again
 result=result.join(" | ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this little snippet:

```
function some_function(qtt, text){
    var final_text = [];
    var parts = text.split("|");
    for(i=0; i<qtt; i++){
        final_text.push(parts[i]);
    }

    final_text.push(" +" + (parts.length - qtt));

    return final_text.join("|");
}
```

Then, call it in this way:

```
var a = "this is a test | test | another string | abc | string test";

some_function(2, a);
//this is a test | +4

some_function(1, a);
//this is a test | test | +3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function below, which I defined as a jQuery plugin, so you can write something like this:

```
$('div').clipText('this is a test | test | another string | abc | string test', ' | ');
```

Here is a working demo with different sized `div` elements which shows how the string is clipped at different positions.

```js
$.fn.clipText = function(text, delim) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var parts = text.split(delim),
            $this = $(this).text('X'),
            height = $this.prop('scrollHeight');
        $this.text(text);
        for (var i = 1; $this.prop('scrollHeight') > height && parts.length; i++) {
            parts.pop();
            $this.text(parts.concat(i + '+').join(delim));
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    $('div').clipText('this is a test | test | another string | abc | string test', 
                      ' | ');
});
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:320px"></div>
<div style="width:310px"></div>
<div style="width:280px"></div>
<div style="width:250px"></div>
<div style="width:210px"></div>
<div style="width:120px"></div>
<div style="width:100px"></div>
```